# Getting state in a stateful monad supporting exceptions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state-monad

I'm trying to figure out how to solve the following problem:
I want a monad that behaves like `State` and `Except`, so I wrote something like this:

```
type ExceptStateM s m a = ExceptT String (StateT s m) a
```

Suppose we don't want to wrap another monad and the state is an `Int`, so we get a monad like this:

```
type MyMonad a = ExceptStateM Int Identity
```

What I'm wondering now is how to get the state from this monad, because the following code:

```
foo :: MyMonad Int
foo = do
    state <- get
    return ()
```

doesn't compile, with the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘ExceptT
                                String (StateT Int Identity) t0’
            with actual type ‘StateT s0 m0 s0’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: state <- get
In the expression:
  do { state <- get;
       return () }
```

I would appreciate some hints on where to look

Comment: Did you import `Control.Monad.Trans.State`? Or `Control.Monad.State`? The first defines `get :: Monad m => StateT s m s`, the latter `get :: MonadState s m => m s`, and only the latter works in this context.

Comment: Also, you want just `foo = get`. Putting in `return ()` throws away the state you got!

Comment: @Zeta yes, this seems to be the problem. Removing the `Trans` from the import does the trick, thanks!

Comment: Please add the `import …` line to your question, as comments can get deleted at any time, and without the `import` it's not answerable.

Comment: @Jytug, see also [`lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) which is closer to what's really going on -- the `Control.Monad.State` thing is kind of a "trick".  You use `lift` to get at the inner layers of a transformer stack, for example: `state <- lift get`.  This works with both modules.